# Possibility to combine keys for asymmetric signature creation

Tags: signature, authentication

There is an asymmetric algorithm which signs with a private key and verifies with a public key. Private and public keys are created in pairs.

Assume we have 2 pairs of private and public keys.

Is there a way to combine two private keys to one private key $priv_{comb}$, so that the produced signature $S$, computed with this $priv_{comb}$, could be verified with either of those two public keys?

It is possible to run the algorithm twice for each pair of keys and produce 2 signatures but it is not an option on resource constraint devices.

Comment: Is it important that you use only one of the public keys when verifying?

Comment: I think it is not important. So it is fine if it is possible to verify with a combination of two public keys or run verification algorithm twice. Verification is done on a resourceful machine, unlike signing.